# VB.NET Sort files in directory by alphanumeric

Tags: vb.net, sorting

How do I sort the files in this directory below by alphanumeric?
An example of a file: 12325_2011.jpg

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(ImagePath)
        Dim imageArray As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        Dim image As IO.FileInfo

        'list the names of all images in the specified directory

        For Each image In imageArray
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(image.Name)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify your existing For Each loop like this:

```
For Each image In imageArray.OrderBy(Function(i) i.Name)
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(image.Name)
Next
```

Comment: Could you explain what Function(i) i.Name is?

Comment: It's a lambda expression - a little mini function with no name that tells the OrderBy function how to compare items in the array for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sorted list class instead of your image array:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx

e.g.

```
For each Item in di.GetFiles
   'Add image url to sorted list
Next


For Each Item in SortedList
    'Add to checkbox list
Next
```