# VB.net Sort File Listed Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

I am trying to sort a gridview that list a directory's files.

I have tried to sort in various different ways from resources like so:

http://forums.asp.net/t/963636.aspx?Default+sort+order+in+GridView
[sorting and paging with gridview asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702600/sorting-and-paging-with-gridview-asp-net)
http://forums.asp.net/t/1076872.aspx?Gridview+how+to+find+a+column+by+it+s+column+name+rather+than+it+s+Cell+index+
http://forums.asp.net/t/963636.aspx?Default+sort+order+in+GridView

However, every time I reload the page the files are not ordered in Ascending order.

I would like to be able to order by the file's "Value" [Column: File Name] since that would give me the results that I want but nothing is working.

I have also tried [VB.NET Sort files in directory by alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611058/vb-net-sort-files-in-directory-by-alphanumeric) like so:

```
For Each filePath As String In filePaths.OrderBy(files)

 files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath))
 'files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath)

Next
```

but get erros from the line `filePaths.OrderBy(files)`
 since the information inside the parenthesis is wrong.

Any suggestions?

**FYI: path for `Directory.GetFiles` is fake for security purposes**

```
Dim filePaths() As String = Directory.GetFiles("\\...\...\uploads\attachments\")

Dim files As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)

  For Each filePath As String In filePaths

    files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath))

  Next

   DisplaySup.DataSource = files
   DisplaySup.DataBind()
   DisplaySup.Sort("File Name", System.Web.UI.WebControls.SortDirection.Ascending)


   'If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(DisplaySup.SortExpression) Then
      'DisplaySup.Sort("SortExpression", SortDirection.Ascending)
      'DisplaySup.DataBind()
   'End If
```

HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="DisplaySup" runat="server" align="center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="Small">
<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Delete File" SortExpression="Value">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:button ID = "btnDelete" cssClass = "submit-btn small" Text = "Delete" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat = "server" OnClick = "DeleteFile" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "File Name" SortExpression="Value">
   <ItemTemplate >
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = '<%# Eval("Value").ToString().Substring(39) %>' CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>

 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#BDBDAE" Font-Underline="False" 
  CssClass="linkNoUnderline" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**UPDATE: I also tried the following example [GridView Sorting Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602015/gridview-sorting-question) and once again the gridview doesn't sort**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to fix my issue.

I referenced: [Sorting Directory.GetFiles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles)

and did the following to pre-sort the directory and then list the files in my gridview:

```
Dim filePaths() As String = Directory.GetFiles("\\...\uploads\attachments\")

'Sort the directory
Dim FilesStr() As String
FilesStr = filePaths
Array.Sort(FilesStr)

'Get each file
Dim files As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)

For Each filePath As String In filePaths

  files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath))
Next

DisplaySup.DataSource = files
DisplaySup.DataBind()
```